# bidirectional zipped stream using boost::iostreams::filtering_stream

Tags: c++, boost, gzip, iostream

Is it possible to create a bidirectional zipped stream using `boost::iostreams::filtering_stream`?  I'd like to have an object that I could read and write to, and have that data zipped/unzipped as it's read into and written from.  I was hoping something like the following would work, but something's clearly not right - on GCC it throws, on MSVC it doesn't throw but the error bit is set on the stream.

[Example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/061e076be6b27079)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        namespace bio = boost::iostreams;
        std::stringstream stream;

        bio::filtering_stream<bio::bidirectional> combined;
        combined.push(bio::combine(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor(), boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor()));
        combined.push(stream);

        combined << "some data" << 42 << 1.23456;

        std::string test;
        combined >> test;
        std::cout << test;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Is this fundamentally not possible?  It would be useful to have this convenience, but if needed I can separate the read/write portions into separate operations.  I'm guessing that I need to call flush() right before any write operations, but not sure how that could wrap into a single object.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. Longer answer, you could design something "similarish" if you know your write patterns are suited for it. Doing so is quite involved.

Comment: As a useful starter hint see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391848/85371

Comment: That's what I thought - or at least that it would be long-winded and fairly restrictive.  If I ever decide to tackle it I'll post it up here.
Thanks for the help :)